# Insert <a href=""> into text string replacing tags

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm trying to find the most beautiful way to replace tags in string with `<a href="">`.

**String:** Text text text %link% text

%link% might me any text between %.

**URL:** https://link.link

**Result:** Text text text a `<href="">`link`</a>` text

Please help me to find the best way to do it.

Thanks!

My solution (maybe the weirdest one):

```
$result = str_rreplace("%", "<a href=\"" . $url . "\">", str_rreplace("%", "</a>", $string));

function str_rreplace($search, $replace, $subject) {
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

    if ($pos !== false) {
        return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: "The most efficient way"? What have you tried so far s we can help from there

Comment: Added my code in post but I don't like it at all.

Comment: ...because? If you don't explain a problem, we cannot help you. "I don't like it" doesn't explain what you don't like. "best" is entirely subjective and down to your opinion. In other words...we don't know what you want, or why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with following solution:

```
$result = preg_replace("/%(.*?)%/", "<a href=\"" . $url . "\">$1</a>", $string);
```